# How to change protected attribute in rails after form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

I think this question is so simple, that I am at a loss for how to google it.

In RoR, if I have a protected attribute like `:premium` or `:admin`, and I only want to change it if a `User` does something specific (signs up for premium account or something as simple as provides a phone number), how would I do that? It should only change if certain conditions are met, but I don't want someone to be able to fake those conditions.

I understand that things like "premimum" or "admin", I want to avoid through mass assignment. So how do you change it if a user fills out a certain form?

Feel free to direct me to any useful links, I just cannot figure out how to word this, but I think it's a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about [Mass Assignment](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html)

You can create **roles**

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name                            # default role
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :premium, :as => :special # 'special' role
```

When calling `.update_attributes(params)` on this model, it will use the default role; if `:premium` is found in `params`, it will throw an error.

In the `POST` method for your special form, you'd specify the `:special` role for the `update_attributes` like `.update_attributes(params, :special)`, directing the `update_attributes` to use the `:special` role which allows the mass assignment of the `:premium` attribute.

You can conditionally pass the role name based on some property in `params`, like the phone number having a value like you mentioned

```
@the_model.update_attributes(params, params[:phone_no].present? ? :special : :default)
```

If these conditions are more complex, you might consider adding them as a class method to the model

```
def self.special_role?(params)
  # fancy conditions here, returning true/false
end
```

and then the `update_attributes` might look like

```
@the_model.update_attributes(params, TheModel.special_role?(params) ? :special : :default)
```

Comment: And using the `:role` option is completely safe against mass assignment?

Comment: I was also having some problems combining that with CanCan. Have to `skip_load_resource :only => ...` so I can add the role. Thanks!